# Plot chart is empty when populated with each-loop

Tags: jquery, json, loops, plot, flot

So I'm tring to plot multiple flot charts in its own div. The data is in json which I have parsed into single jsons. Then I want to for each single json, make a div and plot the single json.

However this doesn't seem to work! I get the (in this example) 3 divs and plotting area is shown, but there is no data - I tested a single json (with no loop) and it worked like a charm.

What am I missing?

Code can be found here: http://dinbab.dk/frank_test/

Comment: Please include code and/or a simple reproducible example in your question.

Comment: Sorry mark, I just had problem with the code marks and I thought there would be to much code...but I'll do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parseJson function from jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).
This way you don't have to do string manipulations.

Instead of this:

```
var shorted_json = json.substring(2,json.length-2);     // Cut away leading and trailing characters from outer json-array
var replaced_json = shorted_json.replace(/},{/g,'o');   // Replace json-object seperator },{ with an 'o'
var splitted_json = replaced_json.split('o');           // Split the json-string for every occurence of the character o;
$.each( splitted_json, function( index, value ){
    var single_json = "{"+value+"}";
    var element = "<div id='placeholder_"+index+"'></div><br>";
    $(document.body).append(element);
    $('#placeholder_'+index).css('height', 500);
    $('#placeholder_'+index).css('width', '100%');
    var options = { ... };

    $.plot('#placeholder_'+index,[single_json],options);

});
```

do this:

```
$.each( $.parseJSON(json), function( index, value ){
    var element = "<div id='placeholder_"+index+"'></div><br>";
    $(document.body).append(element);
    $('#placeholder_'+index).css('height', 500);
    $('#placeholder_'+index).css('width', '100%');
    var options = { ... };

    $.plot('#placeholder_'+index, [value['data']],options);

});
```

See this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/L8fb72h5/